# Grouping and counting fields on a query filtering by date

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've got a query like this (on MS Access 2016):

```
|       City        |  CustomerID  |    OrderID   |   OrderDate   |

|       Venice      |      18      |      45      |   01/01/2015  |
|       Venice      |      18      |      56      |   01/01/2015  |
|       Venice      |      18      |      59      |   03/02/2015  |
|       Venice      |      20      |      60      |   04/02/2015  |
|       Venice      |      20      |      153     |   08/07/2017  |
|        Rome       |      22      |      65      |   05/03/2015  |
|        Rome       |      25      |      68      |   08/03/2015  |
|       Milan       |      27      |      72      |   04/02/2015  |
|       Milan       |      27      |      168     |   04/09/2017  |
```

and I'd like to filter the result by date and get something like this (e.g. filtering by OrderDate between 01/01/2015 and 01/01/2016):

```
|       City        |  CustomerID  |    OrderID   |
|                   |   (Count)    |     (Count)  |
|       Venice      |      2       |      3       |
|        Rome       |      2       |      2       |
|       Milan       |      1       |      1       |
```

Basically:

- *City* field should be picked once as unique
- *CustomerID* field should be picked once if unique and summed whereas is different
- *OrderID* field should be counted

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

MS Access doesn't support `count(distinct)`, but you can do this with two levels of aggregation:

```
select city, count(*) as num_customers, sum(num_orders) as num_orders
from (select city, customerId, count(*) as num_orders
      from <your query here> as t
      group by city, customerId
     ) as t
group by city;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon. What query do you mean by "<your query here>"?

Comment: I replaced "<your query here>" with the query which I started from wrapped by parenthesis but I receive this error when I run the query: "Circular reference caused by alias 'num_orders' in query definition's select list."